# Accessing Eval value inside Gridview Using JQuery OR JavaScript 

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have `gridview` with four `columns`. All the data inside is generated in `RowDataBound` event using `Literals`
eg.

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="ID"  Value='<%#Eval("id")%>' runat="server" />  

                <asp:Literal ID="ltrImage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  

       and

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="lrtBrief" runat="server"></asp:Literal>      
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

In one of these `Literals` I am creating a `<a>` tag and I want to find the `<%#Eval("id")%>` value in `click` event of the `<a>` tag.

I did try something like this but didn't work

```
$('.contactLink').click(function () {

    var grd = $('#MainContent_cphMain_DisplayResults1_gvDisplay');
    var txt = $(grd).find("cells[1].innerHTML").html();

});
```

HTML Looks Like this

```
<td align="center" style="width:5%;">
<input id="MainContent_cphMain_DisplaySearchResults1_gvListing_Listing_0" type="hidden" value="1" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$cphMain$DisplaySearchResults1$gvListing$ctl02$Listing">
  <table class="contact">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <h3>
      <a id="hlContact" class="contactLink format"  runat="server">Contact</a>
      <a id="hlViewF" class="viewLink format" href="CategoriesSearch.aspx?ID=1" runat="server">View </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Any help will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: What does the HTML look like for one of the rows?

Comment: Where is the `hidden` in relation to the `a`? What you're going to need to do is traverse the dom starting at the `a` and look for the `hidden`.

Comment: actually I have four columns in the gridview. In last column I have "a" tag. I can take the hiddenfield to last column if i want. I am using hiddenfied to store the ID which is primary key. Is there any way of obtaining the ID when "a" is clicked

Comment: Yes, by traversing the dom. Without knowing where the `hidden` field is in your html though, we can only speculate on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're missing a closing `h3` around your two links.

```
$(".contactLink").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).closest("table") // Get the <a>'s closest <table>
                       .siblings(":hidden") // <hidden>
                       .val(); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/XFvDF/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for you code. I did add the hiddenfield to that column and tried that code. But its just display "undefined"

Comment: If you can post the html, we can provide more than a guess.

Comment: I have added the HTML in question

Answer (score -1):

if I understand your question right:

> In one of these Literals I am creating a  tag and I want to find
>   the <%#Eval("id")%> value in click event of the  tag.

I would say something like this would do the trick

```
$('a').live("click", function () {
alert($(this).attr("id"))
});
```

Comment: if we using $(this), isn't it referencing to that 'a' tag? will it access the HiddenField value in gridview?